# Getting strange "undefined" on javascript function return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dealing with the following javascript function:

```
function getId() {
    var retval;

    $(document).on('click', '#dlt', function () {
    retval = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
        alert("Here the retval is: " + retval);
    });

    alert(retval);
    return retval;
}
```

I would like to return retval value - it is later used in ajax url to delete some data.

On launch I'm getting following alerts:

1) "Undefined"
2) "Here the retval is 53"

So apparently the function is working (desired number 53 is correct), but I dont understand why the function is returning "undefined". I tried to declare the retval variable globaly, but it didn't work.

Anybody can help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The click is asynchronous.

Comment: is the getId() function inside a $(document).ready?

Comment: By the time the click happens (and triggers your listener) `alert(retval);
    return retval;` have long, long, loooooooooooooong ago been executed.